# Monero blockchain size requirements

Tags: blockchain

I am thinking of running a local node, and I was wondering how much space is needed.

I know that the current blockchain size is less than 50G.

I heard that implementing bulletproofs will significantly shrink the blockchain size.

1. How much space will the full blockchain need if bulletproofs is enabled?
2. When will bulletproofs be enabled?
3. How much space is required now to run a local node? 60GB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Bulletproofs are coming soon, but ensuring they are implemented flawlessly will take priority over meeting any particular schedule. You can follow the Monero dev meeting logs for updates here: https://monerobase.com/

Bulletproofs are a replacement for range proofs, and will greatly reduce their size. However, the size reduction will apply only to new transactions that are added to the blockchain, and not to existing transactions.

Your estimate of around 60GB is correct as of September 2018, but of course you will want to ensure more space is available for the blockchain to grow.